# C++, class member

Tags: c++

Suppose I have two classes. `Class1` takes an instance of `Class2` as an argument to initialize. Then what is the difference between the two lines of code below?

As far as I know, when you use `new`, some memory space are created and you should use `delete` to erase that memory. So is it safe to say in this case the first use is non-standard?

```
Class1 c1(new Class2(argu));

Class1 c1(Class2(argu));
```

Comment: Those two declarations require different prototypes to begin with.

Comment: I like to add that the 1st version is Java style. In C++ it is considered bad style to use "new" unless you are in a constructor. For more information google for "RAII".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `Class1 c1(new Class2(argu));`

The `new` operator allocates a `Class2 object` in the `heap` and you MUST remember to `delete` it when it's no longer in use, otherwise a memory leak will occur. It will call the `Class1(Class2 *p)` constructor. Technically your constructor would have to store that pointer in order to delete it later.

> `Class1 c1(Class2(argu));`

This line creates a temporary object `Class2`, and will always try to call the `Class1(Class2&& c)` constructor that accepts temporary `Class2` objects first.

If you don't have one, it will call `Class1(Class2& c)` [by ref] or `Class1(Class2 c)` [by value] (you only can have one of them at the same time).

Answer (score 0):

`new` allocates a new instance on the heap and returns a pointer to it. In order to accept it your constructor should be defined as `Class1(Class2*)`. The second snippet declares a new instance on the stack and is consumable by a reference `Class1(Class2&)`.

Answer (score 0):

> Then what is the difference between the below two code?

That depends on how the constructor for `Class1` is implemented. For the first construction to succeed;

```
Class1::Class1(Class2* arg);
```

`Class1` needs to accept the argument by pointer (could possibly `const` as well). Further documentation is required to determine whether the argument should be `new`ed or whether it just expects a pointer (if a more C-style is used). Most likely, with modern idiomatic C++, it requires the `new`.

The second constructor requires a reference or value;

```
Class1::Class1(const Class2& arg); // lvalue ref
Class1::Class1(Class2&& arg); // rvalue ref
Class1::Class1(Class2 arg); // value
```

The first form is a copy constructor, the second is a move constructor and both will bind to the temporary `Class2` object created. The third form is by value and will also bind appropriately.

> So is it safe to say in this case the first use is non-standard?

Not at all. If the `Class1` is built to be an RAII type class for the `Class2` resource, then this form is what you would expect.

Note in the case of the `new`, someone needs to call the corresponding `delete` to make sure that the class is destructed and the memory release.

Answer (score -1):

Using new allocates dynamic memory which is used for pointers for the first line. The second line declares a new instance.

You could probably read up on Dynamic memory allocation and also Classes 
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/